# Why I cannot open a txt file

Tags: matlab

I am really a new person in MATLAB and I need use it to finish my homework.

First, I try to open a txt file to get data.
So, I do like this:

```
  folder='C:\Users\yshi20\Desktop\COSC6335\proj_1';
  file='transactionDB.txt';
  myData=fullfile(folder,file);
  [Datafile, message] = fopen('transactionDB.txt', 'r');
```

But the datafile value always show -1 which means it failed to open.

So, I use this to check why I cannot open it:

```
 if Datafile < 0
     disp(message);
     c = [];
 else
     Data = fread(Datafile, 5, 'uint8=>char')'
 end
```

But the result says: `No such file or directory`.
But I checked many times, and I am sure the file name is correct and the location folder is correct, so, how to solve the problem?

Comment: Must be: `[fileID,errmsg] = fopen(myData)`. `myData` is the string that determines which file you want to work with. `fileID` is then file identifier for that file. After get `fileID`, you need to use other functions like `textscan`, `fscanf`, `fgetl`, etc. with the `fileID` to extract information from the file.

Comment: Hint: in Matlab Command Window, type `fopen`, then press `F1`, and read carefully.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong variable.  You need to use `myData` in `fopen`.

```
[Datafile, message] = fopen(myData, 'r');
```

`myData` stores the complete path to your file whereas in your original code, you're using relative referencing which means that it's going to look for the file in the current working directory.   A `-1` code means that it can't find the file... and rightfully so given your error.  It can't find the file in the current working directory.  As such, make sure you change your `fopen` statement so that the correct path to your file is specified.

Comment: Alternatively, `cd` into `folder` and the existing code will work. Though it would make the `fullfile` call redundant.

Comment: as he stated that it was his homework, i would recommend links/hints/guidelines and let him do the rest ...

Comment: @scmg I would imagine the homework part is performing calculations on the data, not loading it in.

Comment: @excaza - You're right.  I think I'll end it here.  I'm sure there's more that the OP needs to do, and I'll leave that as their "homework".

Comment: I do like this: folder='C:\Users\yshi20\Desktop\COSC6335\proj_1';
file='transactionDB.txt';
myData=fullfile(folder,file);
[Datafile, message] = fopen(myData, 'r');   But the result is still -1